How can I forward from a controller to route?
I have an application configured with Spring Cloud Gateway.
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      filter:
        local-response-cache:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: some
          uri: http://other.com
          predicates:
            - ...
          filters:
            - ...

And it works as expected.
Now How can I invoke the route in a controller?
class AnotherController {

    @GetMapping
    Flux<Whatever> readWhatever() {
        // invoke(forward to) the route defined above
        // and transform the response
    }
}


I would have kept it simple and returned a redirect, but if you want for whatever reason it do be done here just call the route with webclient and return the result (e.g. return  webClient.get().uri("/foo").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);)
